# Are there any differences between "de nada" and "por nada"?

Tags: modismos, preposiciones, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

Most of the time in all the Spanish speaking countries I've been in I've heard ***de nada*** as the reply to *gracias* or the equivalent of English *you're welcome* etc.

But after a while I became conscious that sometimes some people were instead saying ***por nada***.

Are they actually used in different grammatical situations? Does the *de* vs *por* depend on something in the topic of what the thanking was about?

Or is it purely up to how the speaker feels, or is one more prevalent in certain places? Or is one less formal or not condoned as official by the RAE?

Comment: In an episode of one of the "Lucy" shows, Ricky said "Por nada" to Lucy in the episode which showed how Lucy met Ricky.

Comment: Hey hippietrail, we miss your questions!

Comment: @fedorqui: Con un poco de suerte podria volver a mexico por la primera vez en ocho anos despues de dos meses si pudiese encontrar un boleto barato desde China. Vamos a ver ...

Comment: Oh, eso sería bueno. Mientras tanto puedes ir reactivando tu castellano en este sitio ;-)

Comment: The expression of courtesy to thank is "de nada". The expression "por nada" is used, for example, in "lo hizo por nada", that is, for free. Or "por nada del mundo, lo haría".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In these Word Reference threads, *"[por nada](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=210100)"*, *"[por nada vs de nada](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=918235)"*, *"[No hay de que; de nada; por nada](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=309777)"*, almost everyone says it's the same expression and it depends on everyone's choice.

But in the second one, someone says *"por nada"* is regarded as *kind of rude* in Spain. I am not sure about this, but I can say that while studying Spanish (*note:* I learnt the one from Spain), I think I never heard *"por nada"* but just *"de nada"*.

And looking up the RAE for the word "[nada](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=nada)", you can see that only *"de nada"* is listed. So maybe, although this doesn't prove about it being rude, it shows it's apparently more spread in the other Spanish speaking countries in Central and South America than in Spain. Perhaps native speakers can confirm this.

Comment: I never thought "por nada" as rude if it's an answer, but you're right in Spain is rarely used. But if someone says "Gracias por nada" it is rude because it means "Thanks for nothing", I think is rude in english too.

Comment: In Spain the usual answers are "de nada" or "no hay de qué". "por/para nada" sounds very weird here. BTW,"que" should be written "qué" in "no hay de qué"

Comment: @Javi the "no hay de que" is directly quoted from the title, so I "can't" change it, but thank you for saying that. :)

Comment: I've heard `por nada` mostly in Mexico but I think `de nada` should be preferred.

Comment: As a clarification, in south america, the two are quite common and never considered rude.

Comment: About the "rude" thing... I just reported someone else said for completeness. But thanks to everybody for your contribution!

Comment: "De nada" (you are welcome) is correct. However, some people incorrectly use "por nada" when they mean "de nada", and you should be ready to infer by context whether they mean "you are welcome" or "thanks for nothing", which, ironically, are kind of opposite in meaning.

Comment: Aleanno, I think this answer is confusing. Is there a source where this rudeness becomes apparent? Maybe you could ask your Spanish contact or teacher again. For "gracias por nada" is said sometimes ironically, when people doesn't help you with something you ask them. But it doesn't have to do with the preposition you choose. :)

Answer (score 1):

*De nada* is usually used as a polite answer after *Gracias*. On the other side *Por nada* is used when you were working on something and you didn't have a result, so you were working for nothing. In my opinion, *Por nada* would be then impolite answer after *Gracias*!

Also, direct translate of the phrases would be:

> De nada = You're welcome
>
> Por nada = For nothing.

Comment: Honestly for me both are the same...we use it in central america to say "your welcome" in a polite way

Comment: I agree with you. In Spain Por nada is absolutely impolite.

Answer (score 0):

de nada is used after Thanks - its means you're welcome - similar to the English  'it was nothing'

por nada is For Nothing.  Gracias por nada. Thanks for Nothing! used rudely if someone didn't do anything for you. I would use it if someone takes up lots of your time and then doesn't follow through.

Comment: I don't think "por nada" is used the same way in all Spanish-speaking countries. It certainly didn't mean "thanks for nothing" when I heard it. It would be good to know which places use which meanings though.

Comment: "Por nada" is a common reply to "Gracias" as well, at least in Latin America.

Answer (score 0):

I spent time in Chile and my understanding is that the two options mean the same thing in general, but "de nada" is more formal. Saying "por nada" implies that whatever the person is being thanked for doing or saying was so simple and easy it doesn't deserve a thank you.

For those thinking it means "Thanks for nothing", remember that, in this context, "por nada" would be a response in conversation and not said by just one person.
Eva: "¿Puedo usar tu lápiz?"
Tomás: "Claro, aquí está."
Eva: "Gracias."
Tomás: "Por nada."

Answer (score -1):

Por nada is more like saying "no problem" than "your welcome", so its a less formal response.