# Ways to say "you're welcome"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

The "textbook" way to say "you're welcome" in Spanish is *de nada*. English has many ways to express this:

- You're welcome.
- No problem.
- Don't worry about it.
- My pleasure.

What other ways are there in Spanish to respond to someone saying *gracias*? If there are many options, what are the most commonly used 4-5?

Comment: related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/854/are-there-any-differences-between-de-nada-and-por-nada

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common ones (of course, which one is *the* most common one, will depend on geographical/regional/cultural considerations):

- De nada.
- Por nada.
- No hay de qué.
- Con mucho gusto.
- Es un placer.

For a discussion on *De nada* y *Por nada*, See [Are there any differences between "de nada" and "por nada"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/854/157)

Comment: +1 for **con mucho gusto** and **es un placer**. These are much closer to the English "you're welcome"; "de nada" is more like "no problem," which doesn't express happiness to have helped someone.

Comment: can we use **"encantado"** for "My pleasure"?

Comment: you've missed the "Don't worry about it." part of the question - I guess spanish would say **"No se preocupe"/"No te preocupes"** to express this. Or maybe **"Tranquilo/a"**, but maybe this sounds more impertinently, like "calm yourself"?

Answer (score 3):

> You're welcome.

In Spain two most popular answers are ***A ti*** and ***De nada***. Especially as a response to single word *gracias*.

***No hay de qué*** is bit more formal, not quite as often used.

> No problem.
>
> Don't worry about it.

***No hay problema*** or ***Sin problema***, although I'd say it's not so often answer to thanks, but rather when asking for someone's help.

> My pleasure.

***(Fue) Un placer***

Answer (score 2):

Is someone says to you **Gracias** you can answer with:

- **De nada:** (You're welcome) This is the most common of all answers.

  > **A:** ¿Me podrías prestar un lápiz?
  >   **B:** Aquí tienes. (Entrega un lápiz).
  >   **A:** Gracias.
  >   **B:** De nada.
- **No hay de qué**: It's a little less common.

  > **A:** No puedo abrir la tapa de esta botella, es muy dura.
  >   **B:** (Abre la botella).
  >   **A:** Ah, gracias.
  >   **B:** No hay de qué.

Is someone has caused a problem, he gives you thanks and you aren't annoyed about the problem:

- **No pasa nada:** (Nothing [bad] happen) It's informal and common.

  > **A:** (Se tropieza con **B**). Ups, perdón.
  >   **B:** No pasa nada.
- **No te preocupes:** (Don't worry about it) It's more formal and also is common.

  > **A:** (Se tropieza con **B**). Ups, perdón, ¿Estas bien?.
  >   **B:** Estoy bien, no te preocupes.
- **No hay problema:** (No problem) It's uncommon.

  > :(, I don't know any example right know.

Also, in another situations you can say:

- **Con mucho gusto:** (¿?) When someone ask you to do something and you are glad of doing the task.
- **Es un placer:** (It's a pleasure)
- **El placer es mio:** (The pleasure is mine) It's used when a person says that it is a pleasure being with you and you say that the pleasure is the opposite, you are pleased of being with him. It's very formal and you can only say it if the another said that it's a pleasure first.
- **El honor es mio:** (The honor is mine) The same as the above but with honor instead of pleasure. I think it's very formal and used only in special events.