# What is the difference between "De nada" and "No hay de qué"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

I am learning Spanish and ran across "De nada" and "No hay de qué". Both mean "You're welcome". What's the difference?

Comment: I would prefer to say :"El placer es mío " . I do find this more polite than "de nada"..This sounds so rude...my opinion.

Comment: But that @user12967 is not an expression in Spanish but a direct translation from English, so I'm afraid none or only English speaking people would say that in Spanish...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's just a matter of regional preferences.

*No hay de qué* might be a bit more formal in some contexts, but they mean exactly the same.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets a “don’t worry about it” sense from  *No hay de qué*?

Answer (score 9):

There is another way in Spain:

> No hay por qué darlas

It means that you don't need to thank me because helping you was easy for me, or our personal relation is so strong that helping you is taken for granted. Actually, the three forms have the same sense, as 'De nada' and 'No hay de qué' can be considered shorter forms of 'No hay por qué darlas'.

All the three forms are common, with 'De nada' being the most common due to its shortness.

Comment: If you say "No hay por qúe darlas" in Mexico people will screw with you. That's because "darlas" can also be tought as "dar las nalg** a alguien". In Mexico that's called "alburear". You can find the definition here: http://rae.es/alburear

Comment: Yup, that is a totally no-no in Mexico, it'd imply a sexual innuendo more commonly known as "albur"

Comment: In Spain we use 'de nada', while  in several southamerican countries they say 'para nada'.

Comment: @JLPrieto - Are you sure you didn't mean to write "por nada"?

Comment: @aparente001 a mate from argentina usually says 'para nada' and sometimes 'por nada'. I have to ask him about the difference.

Comment: @JLPrieto - We can also ask here at Spanish Language StackExchange!  That will make a great question.

Comment: @aparente001 we already have that question! [Are there any differences between “de nada” and “por nada”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/854/1674)

Comment: cc @JLPrieto ^^

Answer (score 6):

In Mexico `de nada` - or `por nada`- is a common reply to `gracias`. I am now studying Spanish in Costa Rica where they take `de nada` more literally hence offensive. To the locals `de nada` means more like "it was unimportant and I don't care".

Here the appropriate response to `gracias` is **mucho gusto** ("it's my pleasure").

Similarly `me da igual` is appropriate while `no me importa` is somewhat offensive.

Comment: ```me da igual``` is not equivalent in any way to ```de nada``` in most of the Spanish speaking countries, I agree that's rude to reply that to a ```gracias``` but it's not the same meaning that ```de nada```.

Comment: @EugenioMiró - There's no connection in meaning.  User540 only meant, by the way, here is another interesting case where two phrases that in some regions are equivalent, carry a very different tone.

Answer (score 2):

They both serve the same function and the difference is a matter of style/nuance. In English, you might say one of the following:

> you're welcome
>
> my pleasure
>
> no problem
>
> of course

Or any number of other variations. In Spanish you'll find the same is true:

> de nada
>
> no hay de qué
>
> faltaría más

Answer (score 2):

I'm beginning to learn Spanish as well. I just learned of the phrase, "No hay de que'" and had the same question. When I typed out the individual words in the phrase for literal meaning they mean the following: (Español/English)

No = no;

hay = there is;

de = of;

que = what.

The direct English translation would be, "No there is of what." The "correct" translation would be, "There is no of what." There are several English sayings that have a similar context such as, "What of it?" or "There is nothing to it." or "Make nothing of it."

This is similar to, "De nada." Which is, "Of nothing". The English phrase similar to this is: "It is nothing."

At least this is how I'm rationalizing the Spanish to English context beyond the literal translation.

I hope that helps. Happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

***No hay de qué*** might have been built in the early 19<sup>th</sup> century upon the French:

> ***Il n'y a pas de quoi***

The latter being a shortcut of

> *Il n'y a pas de quoi **me remercier***

i.e.

> There is no reason to thank me
>
> This is not something that I deserve to be thank for

Answer (score 0):

*No hay de que*, translates directly to "No There of that" or "There's none of that".

I have heard people say it translates to "don't mention it" but I think it really means means "there is no need to thank", which people interpret "it was my pleasure". However, it would be like English people saying "there is no need to thank", which we really don't say. or everyone once in a while you hear it.

Comment: this is true, but this is the beauty of idioms: they are not to be translated literally

Answer (score 0):

In Argentina it is: *No hay por qué*.

It is sort of diminishing, like: "no, it was nothing" or "you have no reason to thank me, it was nothing."

Answer (score 0):

### Reply to *gracias*

> Fue un placer

Very polite

---

> A la orden / a sus órdenes

Express subordination

---

> ¿De qué?

Quite common although a bit rude

---

> De nada / por nada / no es nada

Very common

---

> No hay por qué / No hay de qué

Very common

---

> No hay por que darlas

You can use it; but, in Mexico, you will get a reply. So be aware!

---

> Las que hace el chango / las que hace el perro

[Naco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naco_(argot)): Bad taste; great lack of style

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are responses to "thank you" that diminish the importance of the thing given. "De nada" means you're thanking me for nothing. "No hay de que" literally means "there is nothing for which" (in other words, there is nothing for which to thank me.)

The rough equivalent in English is "you're welcome." Even though English takes a different tack from Spanish (and French). Rather than diminish the thing given, English indicates that you're thanking someone for something you were always welcome to have.

Of the two expressions, "de nada" is less formal and what you'd expect to hear among friends and family members. "No hay de que" is slightly more formal and you'd expect to hear it when thanking someone in a professional context, although "de nada" could be used there as well.

Answer (score 0):

De nada: literal translation is close to, "It was nothing." 
but as everyone knows, the usage is pretty much exactly translated to, "You're welcome."

No hay de que: literal translation is close to, "No reason to thank me."
but the feeling is more formal, closer to, "It was my pleasure."

This is based on my experience, and this obviously varies among different Latin cultures.

Answer (score -3):

*"De nada"* purely means, "you're welcome", but not literally. *"No hay de qué"* more directly translates to, "It's my pleasure." This is what I have gathered from just several years in learning Spanish.

Answer (score -3):

`De Nada` means `you're welcome`.
`No hay de qué` can mean, `don't mention it`, `it was nothing`, `think nothing of it`, pretty much a more elaborate form of thank you.