# Origen de "No hay de qué", ¿a qué se refiere "qué"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, cortesía, pronombre-interrogativo

Tras leer esta pregunta: [What is the difference between "De nada" and "No hay de qué"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/what-is-the-difference-between-de-nada-and-no-hay-de-qu%C3%A9)

Me preguntaba, ¿de dónde viene la expresión "no hay de qué"? En concreto me interesa saber a qué hace referencia el "qué".

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de las etiquetas, si considerais que falta alguna por favor editad la pregunta para incluirlas :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión "no hay de qué" se usa desde antiguo seguida de diferentes verbos:

- *No hay de qué maravillarse deso* (Quijote, 1605).
- *No hay de qué nos asombremos* (Guzmán de Alfarache, 1599).
- *No hay de qué maravillaros de eso* (Portacuentos, 1564).
- *No hay de qué hacerme á mí culpado* (Rebelión y castigo de los moriscos, 1600).

Sin embargo, los primeros casos de la expresión sin verbo seguida son del siglo XVIII, y curiosamente no se usaba para responder a un *gracias*, sino a otra expresión:

> *D. Gil.: Señores, sea en hora buena:
>
>               y recibid mi deseo
>
>               de que os gocéis muchos años.
>
>   Novia: No es aqueste caballero
>
>               mi esposo.
>
>   D. Gil: La cercanía
>
>               me persuadió el parentesco;
>
>               perdonadme.
>
>   D. Joaq: No hay de qué.*
>
> Ramón de la Cruz, "El reverso del sarao", 1766 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Doctor: ¿Es usted el mayordomo?
>
>   Señor 2.º: No, señor.
>
>   Doctor: Pues se parece. Perdone usted.
>
>   Señor 2.º: No hay de qué.*
>
> Ramón de la Cruz, "La enferma del mal de boda", 1757 (España).

Así pues, el primer caso del CORDE conteniendo esta expresión se usó para una respuesta a una disculpa, por lo que "no hay de qué" significaría "no hay de qué disculparse". Ya entrado el siglo XIX vemos casos de la expresión tanto como respuesta a una disculpa como a un agradecimiento:

> *—Perdone V., caballero.
>
>   —No hay de qué...*
>
> Ramón de Mesonero Romanos, "Escenas de 1832", 1832 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *DON EDUARDO: Quede usted con Dios, señor don Pedro, y mil gracias de todos modos.
>
>   DON PEDRO: No hay de qué, amigo mío, no hay de qué...*
>
> Manuel Eduardo de Gorostiza, "Contigo pan y cebolla", 1833 (México).

Casos similares nos podemos encontrar en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *—Mil gracias por haberme sugerido esta idea, querido doctor. —No hay
>   de que, señor conde.*
>
> Diario balear. 26/2/1830, página 4.
>
> ---
>
> *—Perdone usté caballero. —No hay de qué...*
>
> Cartas españolas. 5/1–29/3/1832, página 182.

Nótese que la expresión "no hay de qué" es lo suficientemente laxa como para poder ser completada con muchos y variados verbos, como se vio al principio de esta respuesta. Eso la hace muy versátil y por tanto susceptible de ser usada como respuesta para diferentes situaciones, aunque hoy día solo se suela usar para corresponder a un agradecimiento. En este caso, se puede entender que la expresión completa sería "no hay de qué dar las gracias".

Comment: tus respuestas son increíbles, si para mañana no te han sobrepasado (dudo bastante que alguien pueda dar una respuesta mas investigada y mejor redactada la verdad) te pongo el tic.

Answer (score 6):

En mi opinión, tal y como yo lo entiendo, vendría a significar "no hay de qué estar agradecido", es decir, quitas importancia al asunto por el que te están dando las gracias.

En este aspecto se parece a la expresión más literal y quizás menos utilizada "no hay por qué darlas".